# Hashed Password with EF 4.1 Database first / ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm rolling my own authentication system and I've run into a situation that I need guidance on.

I'm *not* using EF 4.1 code first. I've designed my database to include a User table with an Id, Email and HashedPassword column. I then let EF create an entity based off this table. I then created a partial class to handle my validation.

The problem is that within my view I want to have a textbox for email, password and confirm password. I need validation on password and confirm password (required and compare). I can add these to the validation class I created but because they aren't part of the entity EF created for the User table, I get compiler errors when I try to view the page.

My partial class

```
[MetadataType(typeof (UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User
    {
        private class UserMetadata
        {
            [Required]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Compare("Password")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

My view

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
    </p>
     <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
    </p>

    <p class="button">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
}
```

My model

Table Name: Users
Columns: Id, Email, HashedPassword

How can I get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Might be helpful to see how it's implemented to see how the compilation errors might occur.

Comment: Vasile Bujac is correct. You should create a model that is only for the View and not use your DataModel for that. Then you map the properties over from one to the other. This allows you to have properties that are visible to the user that may not exist in the database but are either used or mapped to the appropriate columns in your DataModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward answer seems to be to make a ViewModel that has the `Password` and `ConfirmPassword` fields for the MVC part. When you're actually ready to save to the database, use that to create the EF model version with `HashedPassword` instead.

That said, I've used properties that don't exist in the EF model in my views without a ViewModel by adding them with a partial class as you're trying. I think the issue is that you have these inside the Metadata class, when they're not really metadata. Try this instead:

```
[MetadataType(typeof (UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    private class UserMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }


    }
}
```

This version defines a couple new properties, and then changes the metadata on Email to add `[Required]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your view's model is the User entity itself, which doesn't define a ConfirmPassword property. I would recommend that you create an entirely new view-model class, than you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to easily map between these two classes.